# Sum of last k digits same as sum of first k digits

Tags: algorithm

I want to find if sum of first k digits of few numbers in given range is equal to sum of last k digits. Here the range is very large and k is less than 20.

One way we can do this is by brute force method. Can someone suggest some other efficient algo. for same?

Comment: Could you clarify with some examples ?

Comment: @HamZa why? what did you not understand?

Comment: who needs that? and for which application you need an better than straight forwars solution?

Comment: It is still not clear what you mean by "few numbers in a given range". Do you need to compare the sum of first k and last k digits for all numbers in a proper n, n+1, n+2, ... m (n<m) range? Do you pick out some of the numbers in such a range? If so, do you know if they are consecutive? Please edit your question.

Comment: Are you going to use the same array only once or a lot of times?

Comment: In one of variants where you have numbers of exactly `N` digits w/o leading 0s, like `101, 102, ...`, good chances there are purely math formula for this: if you have numbers of `N` digits, `N >= 2k`, your answer is `X * 10^(N-2k)`, where `X` is the number of `lucky tickets of 2k digits w/o leading 0`. There's closed-form formula for `2k-digits lucky ticket numbers with leading 0s` here (in Russian): http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82#.D0.AF.D0.B2.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D1.83.D0.BB.D1.8B

Comment: Here's Wolfram link with count of `for 6-digit lucky ticket numbers`: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28integrate+%28sin+10x+%2F+sin+x%29%5E6+dx+from+x%3D0+to+pi%29+%2F+pi

Answer (score 1):

If it is a range, the first digits will not change often and the last digits will change in a simple way. S is the sum of the first 20 digits. While the secund digit doesn't change, the sum will be increased by one when you go to the next digit. So if all yours digits, except the last one, are fixed, and if the sum with the last digit equal to i is Si, you the only good last digit is n= S - Si + i. You then have to check if n is between 0 and 9, and if the resulting number is in the interval. This decrease by ten the number of lookups.

You can check for the next secund lower digits.
If the first n is lower than 0, you need to decrease the secund digit by -n. Call n2 this secund digit. If n2 > = 0, the good numbers will end by  (n2,0), (n2 -1,1), ..., (0, n2). This decrease the complexity by 100.
If n is bigger than 10, you increase the second digit by n-9. Call n2 the second digit. If n2<=9, the good numbers are (n2,9),(n2-1,8),...,(0,something).
This also decrease the complexity by 100.

You can do the same for the third digit, and then for the fourth, up to the 20. This will result in just 1 sum, and a complexity in O(number of solutions), so it is minimal. For coding, be careful that your firsts numbers can change. Do one computation per group of 20 first numbers.

Answer (score 0):

one theoretical improvement to the brute force method:

1) sum up the frist k digits, store in `sumFirst`
2) sum up the last k digits, but stop if sum exceeds `sumFirst`.

Point 2 could save summing up some of the last few digits.

But you have to measure if the additional logic, costs more then simply adding all k digits.

Comment: There is a lot more way for improvement, if the original question makes it clear whether there are additional constraints on the "few numbers in a given range". Hence the need for clarifying the question.

Comment: It's not true that this will save 50% on average. If the sum is exceeded it will usually happen near the end, so the savings will be much closer to zero.

Comment: @interjay you are correct, i have updated. probably you cannot improve the brute force by algorithmic means.

Answer (score 0):

another improvement over the brute force:

```
i = 0, T = 0
while |T| < 9 * (k - i) 
  T = T + last[i] - first[i]
  i = i + 1
return T == 0
```

Comment: If they are equal T will be 0 at the end. If the sum from one side exceeds the maximum possible compensation with remaining (k - i) digits, absolute value of T will be greater than 9 * (k - i).

Comment: Provide initial value of T

Comment: i think calculating the abs(T) costs more then the gain.

Answer (score 0):

*Optimization  N-k*

One way to improve the algorithm is if when the number having N digits has the following property:
`N < 2k`.

For instance if N = 5 and k = 3, `5 < 2x3`, digits being

```
abcde
```

you only have to count `ab` against `de` (ie no need to check `k` (3) digits, since the 3<sup>rd</sup> is shared by k-last and k-first digits).
In other words, the number of digits to be counted both sides is only

```
min(k, N-k), having N >= k
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use that multiple times for the same array, you can sum all element with previous elements which is `O(n)` where the size of array is `n` i.e

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
     arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i-1];
```

This will convert your array from [probability density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution_function) to [cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (for discrete numbers). Therefore your query is going to be `O(1)` i.e.

```
if(arr[k-1] == (arr[n-1]-arr[n-k])) //arr[k-1] is sum of first k element
    return true;
return false;
```